# MYSQL - How to cast a field in depending on its value?

Tags: mysql

I have complex SQL-Statements with `group_concat` and i need sometimes to convert the value. So i use something like this (Its an example):

```
SELECT IF(1=1,CAST(TEST AS CHAR),CAST(TEST AS UNSIGNED)) 
FROM(
SELECT '40' as TEST
UNION 
SELECT '5' as TEST
UNION 
SELECT '60' as TEST
) as t1
ORDER BY TEST ASC;
```

Should return CHAR, returns CHAR.

```
SELECT IF(1=0,CAST(TEST AS CHAR),CAST(TEST AS UNSIGNED)) 
FROM(
SELECT '40' as TEST
UNION 
SELECT '5' as TEST
UNION 
SELECT '60' as TEST
) as t1
ORDER BY TEST ASC;
```

Should return UNSIGNED, returns CHAR

So the result of IF condition is always a CHAR and need to be CAST.

How i can resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL tries to figure out the column type just by parsing the SQL, not based on runtime conditions like the way an `IF()` expression goes. While your example allows the result of the `IF()` to be determined before actually processing any rows, this is not true in general and MySQL doesn't perform this optimization.

It just sees that the `IF()` can return either `UNSIGNED` or `CHAR`, and figures out a common type that both can be converted to safely. This is `CHAR`.

This is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

> The default return type of `IF()` (which may matter when it is stored into a temporary table) is calculated as follows:
>
> - If *expr2* or *expr3* produce a string, the result is a string.
> - If *expr2* and *expr3* are both strings, the result is case-sensitive if either string is case sensitive.
> - If *expr2* or *expr3* produce a floating-point value, the result is a floating-point value.
> - If *expr2* or *expr3* produce an integer, the result is an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I need an unsigned value for my issue. How can I implement this?

Comment: Don't cast to `CHAR` if you always need an `UNSIGNED`.

Comment: I need to cast well sometimes i need a CHAR.                                     
`SELECT IF(TEST='(div.)',CAST(TEST AS CHAR),CAST(TEST AS UNSIGNED)) 
FROM(
SELECT IF(instr(group_concat(1,',',2,',',3,',',4,',',5),',')>0,'(div.)',40) as TEST
UNION 
SELECT '5' as TEST
UNION 
SELECT '60' as TEST
) as t1;`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why do you have that `IF()` if you always need `UNSIGNED`?

Comment: Remember, the datatype of a column is an attribute of the whole result set, you can't have different datatypes on different rows.

Comment: i use `group_concat`  from an integer field. if this field have different values then the value is an char.

Comment: i know that the datatype is bind on column. this is why i use the if condition. if a textfield in my application is filled then the cast have to be unsigned.

Comment: My goal is to present the orders and their positions bundled in an order summary. But I also use the same sql statement to represent an order single view.

In the overall order overview, the article numbers are displayed as number positions and again in the single view the individual article number. Based on the same SQL statement.

Comment: All rows in a result set have to have the same datatypes for the columns. If some rows have `'(div.)'` as the value, then all rows have to have `CHAR` as the datatype.

Comment: When you're presenting the results, you can't tell the difference between `CHAR` and `UNSIGNED`. Just let everything get cast to `CHAR`.

Comment: In summary view need to be `CHAR` in single view need to be `UNSIGNED` (well there is no '(div.)' in single view). I ultimately committed to the unsigned value. Many thanks for the explanation regarding the `IF` condition and the behavior of mysql at different value types.

Comment: the `IF`condition is the external indicator, whether the result contains `char` values. Although the result does not contain any `char` values ​​and the cast function is supposed to declare the column `UNSIGNED`, the `IF` condition declares the column as `CHAR`.- Well: If expr2 or expr3 produce a string, the result is a string.

Comment: You could put the indicator in a different column. You can also put the char and unsigned results in different columns.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you're trying to do in total. Post a new question, and show the actual result you're trying to obtain.

Comment: Sometimes asking a question that's too specific obscures the real problem. See [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)